# How to block all goroutines except the one running

Tags: go

I have two (but later I'll be three) go routines that are handling incoming messages from a remote server (from a ampq channel). But because they are handling on the same data/state, I want to block all other go routines, except the one running.

I come up with a solution to use `chan bool` where each go routine blocks and then release it, the code is like:

```
package main

func a(deliveries <-chan amqp, handleDone chan bool) {
    for d := range deliveries {
        <-handleDone        // Data comes always, wait for other channels
        handleDone <- false // Block other channels

        // Do stuff with data...

        handleDone <- true // I'm done, other channels are free to do anything
    }
}

func b(deliveries <-chan amqp, handleDone chan bool) {
    for d := range deliveries {
        <-handleDone
        handleDone <- false
        // Do stuff with data...
        handleDone <- true
    }
}

func main() {
    handleDone := make(chan bool, 1)
    go a(arg1, handleDone)
    go b(arg2, handleDone)
    // go c(arg3, handleDone) , later

    handleDone <- true // kickstart
}
```

But for the first time each of the function will get `handleDone <- true`, which they will be executed. And later if I add another third function, things will get more complicated. How can  block all other go routines except the running? Any other better solutions?

Comment: I don't think your channels do what you think they do, since you're never checking the received value. Anyway, using a buffered channel as a mutex/semaphore can be dangerous. Use an actual Mutex instead.

Comment: Note that they are called "goroutines", not "go routines". This is because the word "routine" might refer to any procedure/function in any procedural PL, hence "go routines" sounds like "routines in Go" which makes the intended meaning of the term disappear.

Answer (score 6):

You want to look at the sync package.

http://golang.org/pkg/sync/

You would do this with a mutex.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an incoming stream of messages and you have three goroutines listening on that stream and processing and you want to ensure that only one goroutine is running at a time, the solution is quite simple:  kill off two of the goroutines.

You're spinning up concurrency and adding complexity and then trying to prevent them from running concurrently.  The end result is the same as a single stream reader, but with lots of things that can go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I'm puzzled why you want this - why can't each message on `deliveries` be handled independently? and why are there two different functions handling those message? If each is responsible for a particular type of message, it seems like you want one `deliveries` receiver that dispatches to appropriate logic for the type.

But to answer your question, I don't think it's true that each function will get a `true` from `handleDone` on start. One (let's say it's `a`) is receiving the `true` sent from `main`; the other (`b` then) is getting the `false` sent from the first. Because you're discarding the value received, you can't tell this. And then both are running, and you're using a buffered channel (you probably want `make(chan bool)` instead for an unbuffered one), so confusion ensues, particularly when you add that third goroutine.

The `handleDone <- false` doesn't actually accomplish anything. Just treat any value on `handleDone` as the baton in a relay race. Once a goroutine receives this value, it can do its thing; when it's done, it should send it to the channel to hand it to the next goroutine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment's. I've changed some parts of the code. I removed the `false`s. But it get now stack and it just wait's there. It just wait at `<-handleDone` in both go function. Seems they don't get the true from the main.

Comment: What's `main` doing then? has it reached `handleDone <- true`?

Comment: The problem is, after `handleDone <- true`, `func a()` just waits for `func b()`, however in my case `func b()` could not executed at all. All I want is at any time, if one of the go routines(`a()`, `b()`, etc.. is running than all others should just wait until the running one is finished.

Comment: Ahh, right. I led you astray when I suggested not using a buffered channel. Buffering actually makes sense in that case.